# How do I link to a static image inside a css file?

Tags: python, pylons, pyramid

newb to pyramid and python. I've been able to link to my static files successfully in any of my jinja2 templates, ie:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{'myproject:static/mycss.css'|static_url}}"></link>
```

The .css file loads fine and I can link to any images that are inside my static folder as long as I do it within the jinja template.

I'd like to use an image as a background but am having trouble linking to the image in my css file:

```
#mydiv{
background-image:url("{{'myproject:static/myimage.gif'|static_url}}");
}
```

This link shows up in mycss.css as

`"{{'myproject:static/myimage.gif'|static_url}}"`

and doesn't show up as a link. (if I load an externally hosted image as my background-image it works)

thx!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your CSS file is a static file, and thus is *not* treated as a template. All static resources are served as-is, without any processing.

All non-absolute URLs in a CSS file are relative to the location from where the CSS file has been loaded; if you use `background-image:url("myimage.gif")`, the browser loads the image relative to your CSS file location. Since the CSS was loaded from `http://yoursite/static/mycss.css`, the image will be loaded from `http://yoursite/static/myimage.gif`.

Alternatively, if you referencing files from unusual locations (for example, images auto-generated by one of your views), you'll have to add your CSS file as a view instead, and render it with a (text) template.

Comment: I'm loyal. You answered first and it works. You've been very helpful and I appreciate it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I edited your answer to swap the options, because "just use relative urls" answer is correct for 99.5% of all cases, and a